# .insertBefore creating duplicates

Tags: jquery, duplicates

I'm trying to use .insertBefore to move an element ahead of one that is several levels above it. Of course the problem I'm running into is that it's duplicating the content because my parent divs all have the same class, which I can't change. How can run .insertBefore for each div without affecting the others? I need to put post-title above image-frame.

This is what I have so far. Thank you!

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#post-item").each(function(){
    $(".post-title").insertBefore(".image_frame");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="post-item">
<p class="image_frame">Was on top</p>
<p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
<p class="post-title">Was on bottom</p>
</div>

<div id="post-item">
<p class="image_frame">Was on top1</p>
<p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
<p class="post-title">Was on bottom1</p>
</div>

<div id="post-item">
<p class="image_frame">Was on top2</p>
<p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
<p class="post-title">Was on bottom2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't have duplicate IDs. Change `id="post-item"` to `class="post-item"`. `$("#post-item")` will only select the first one, not the repetitions, because IDs are assumed to be unique.

Then, to solve your problem, use `$(this).find()` to refer to just an item within the current element of the iteration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".post-item").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".post-title").insertBefore($(this).find(".image_frame"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-item">
  <p class="image_frame">Was on top</p>
  <p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
  <p class="post-title">Was on bottom</p>
</div>

<div class="post-item">
  <p class="image_frame">Was on top1</p>
  <p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
  <p class="post-title">Was on bottom1</p>
</div>

<div class="post-item">
  <p class="image_frame">Was on top2</p>
  <p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
  <p class="post-title">Was on bottom2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are looping over every post-item

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#post-item").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".post-title").insertBefore(".image_frame");
});
});
```

Now there is one more problem , you are using id , which only selects one dom element , you need to either rename post-item from id to class like below

```
<div class="post-item">
<p class="image_frame">Was on top</p>
<p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
<p class="post-title">Was on bottom</p>
</div>

<div class="post-item">
<p class="image_frame">Was on top1</p>
<p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
<p class="post-title">Was on bottom1</p>
</div>

<div class="post-item">
<p class="image_frame">Was on top2</p>
<p class="otherDiv">Middle Stuff</p>
<p class="post-title">Was on bottom2</p>
</div>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".post-item").each(function(){
   var post=  $(this).find(".post-title");
   var frame = $(this).find(".image_frame");
   post.insertBefore(frame);
});
});
```

For find another way to select all post-items

My fiddle with correction https://jsfiddle.net/shyamjoshi/xpvt214o/204223/

Comment: Need to use `.find()` for `.image_frame` as well.